# Highcharts - column chart with drilldown to waterfall

Tags: charts, highcharts, drilldown, waterfall

I have a strange behavior with my drill down to a waterfall chart. My middle column which is a negative value is not positioned on the top, instead it is going from zero down.

I have taken the exact same configuration and applied it to a first level waterfall chart and there it works fine.

- Expected result: Column 'Discount' should go from 50 to 40
- Actual result: Column 'Discount' goes from 0 to -10

JSfiddle for drilldown chart where waterfall is not as I want it:

[Drilldown][1]

JSfiddle for chart where waterfall is correct:

[Waterfall][2]

I can not figure out what is missing.

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/a5x2g0q8/
  [2]: https://jsfiddle.net/jfgycycp/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Highcharts example of [Drilldown from column to pie](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/across-types/), you need to set the chart `type` to be the drilled down type, i.e. to `'waterfall'`, and set the `type` of the top level series explicitly, i.e. to `'column'`.

Updated chart options with `type`:

```
chart: {
  type: 'waterfall',
  height: 350,
  zoomType: 'xy'
},
```

Updated top level series options with `type`:

```
series: [{
  type: 'column',
  data: [
  {
    name: 'Sweden',
    y: 55,
    drilldown: 'Sweden'
  }]
}],
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/8seh9w49/)